# Find all permutations (passwords) generated from characters.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A program for generating random computer passwords gives one lowercase letter, one upper-case letter, two digits ($0$ through $9$), and three letters that may be upper-case or lower-case. How many possible passwords can this program produce?

It is a question from the *Introduction to Combinatorics*, Second Edition
by Walter D. Wallis, John C. George.

My Solution to it is - $26 \cdot 26 \cdot 52 \cdot 52 \cdot 52 \cdot 10 \cdot 10 \cdot 6 \cdot 6$ where factor of $6$ is for selecting position for digits between letters.

Is this answer right (I am confused between whether $6 \cdot 7$ should come or $6 \cdot 6$ is correct) ?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: We have to be careful here since the number of permutations that can be formed depends on whether there are repeated characters.  Selecting the positions of the digits is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 7 characters in the password, and two are digits.
In how many ways can we select which 2 out of the 7 characters which are to be digits? (Hint: $6\cdot 6$ is not correct, $6\cdot 7$ is better but also not correct. Do you know Combinations? )

Once you account for the placement of the digits, and their values (the $10\cdot 10$ in your answer, which is correct) you have to deal with the letters. The problem is that you cannot designate a single location that is to be the letter that is forced to be upper case, because there are those three letters that are free to be either upper or lower case. Similarly with the letter that is forced to be lower case. In the completed password, there is no way to uniquely determine which character was the one forced to be upper case (unlike numerical digits). Choosing any specific one to be upper case would lead to double counting.

So let's ignore upper/lower case at first. That would leave $26 \cdot 26 \cdot 26 \cdot 26 \cdot 26$ choices for the letter values.

How many possibilities are there of choosing the case of all the letters if there were no restrictions on your choice? Now what restrictions does this password algorithm put on whether the letters can be upper or lower case?

Comment: So ,is this correct 26⋅26⋅52⋅52⋅52⋅10⋅10⋅(7C2)(5C2) . (7C2) is for selecting 2 digits from 7 and (5C2) is for selecting two characters out of 5.

Comment: @joy The (7C2) is correct, but the letters part is not because of the double counting I warned about. The password AAAaa00 could be generated by choosing the first letter to be upper case, the 5th letter to be lower case, and the 2nd to 4th letters to be any case (which happened to be upper/upper/lower). It can also be generated by choosing the 2nd letter to be upper case the 4th letter to be lower case, and case of the 1st, 3rd, 5th letters any case. This is why choosing which two letters are the forced upper/lower case ones will be wrong. Reread the last two paragraphs of my answer for hint.

Comment: Ok.I got it 26⋅26⋅26⋅26⋅26⋅10⋅10⋅(7C2)(2^5-2) is the answer.(2^5-2) factor is due to  every character got two choices which is 32 subtracted by when all are lowercase or uppercase i.e 2

Comment: @joy: Well done, you got it.